# How to implements Objects (like Javascript) in C++?

Tags: javascript, c++

How can I implement data-structure in c++ that behaves like Javascript objects having key value pairs.

```
var a = {
    "key1" : value1,
    "key2" : value2,
}
console.log(a["key1"]);
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: Maps are the closest thing I can think off

Answer (score 3):

Could use `std::map`, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> a{ {"key1", 1},{"key2", 2},{"key3", 3} };
    std::cout << a["key2"] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/cfK0xH

Answer (score 2):

If you want list of key value pairs, [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) could be an option:

```
std::map<std::string,int> key_value_pair_list;
key_value_pair_list.emplace("key1",5);
key_value_pair_list.emplace("key2,10);
std::cout << key_value_pair_list["key1"];
```